# convergence in probability of random variable

Tags: probability, asymptotics

Suppose that the sequence of random variable converges in probability to zero,  $X_n=o_p(1)$. How can I show that
$$P(\lvert e^{X_n}-1\rvert>c)\to 0, \text{ as } n\to\infty, \forall c>0?$$

Help me if you have any hint. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: If $X_n$ converges in probability to $X$, and $f$ is a continuous function, then also $f(X_n)$ converges in probability to $f(X)$.

Comment: @DominikKutek Thank you! This is sufficient.